# Bibliography header does not change

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, chapters

I am using the book style for my thesis but the header of my last chapter always appears above my bibliography and i can't get it to change. I do not want any header on top of my bibliography page or a new header 'Bibliography'. Both are fine. I used markboth as in the code below (which i found on this site), but it does not work.

```
\include{chapters/Chapter1}
\include{chapters/Chapter2}
\include{chapters/Chapter3}
\include{chapters/Chapter4}
\include{chapters/Chapter5}
\include{chapters/Chapter6}

\cleardoublepage

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\markboth{Bibliography}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Here are two pictures to show the problem. The first one is the start of my biblio which is ok. The second page of my bib however starts with the header of my previous chapter...

[image]
[image]

I searched everywhere but can't find an answer that works for me

Comment: Djorren, I am not sure if your question is clear. What do you want exactly? Please, provide a minimum working example so that we can see what is wrong.

Comment: I do not want the header of my previous chapter to appear on my bibliography page...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have not defined your headers for your desired style. You could use `\nouppercase` in the headings commands. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample Chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use \lhead{Chapter 6. \emph{Conclusion}} at the top of my chapter file

Comment: @Djorren - So you need to provide a different `\lhead` directive at the start of the bibliography.

Comment: @Djorren, as Mico suggests, just try to modify your headers in the way I've written. And please, if it responds to your question, set my response as answer.